# How can I execute a command in each subdirectory of a folder?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, file-io, command-line

I have a folder with more folders within folder.

I'm looking to make all files at a certain "level" be moved up one.

For example I have:

> - ParentFolder\Actor1\Movie\HighRes\HighresMovie.mp4
> - ParentFolder\Actor1\Movie\LowresMovie.mp4
> - ParentFolder\Actor2\Movie\HighRes\HighresMovie.mp4
> - ParentFolder\Actor2\Movie\LowresMovie.mp4

But I want it to look like:

> - ParentFolder\Actor1\Movie\HighresMovie.mp4
> - ParentFolder\Actor1\Movie\LowresMovie.mp4
> - ParentFolder\Actor2\Movie\HighresMovie.mp4
> - ParentFolder\Actor2\Movie\LowresMovie.mp4

This is a massive folder with about 1000 "Actor" folders.

I currently have this command line command partially working:

```
for /f "delims==" %i in ('dir /a:d /b') do for /f "delims==" %f in ('dir "%i" /a:d /b') do (move "%i\%f\*.*" "%i"&&rd "%i\%f" /s /q)
```

I can run this command from the command line within the "Actor" folder and it does exactly what I want. Now I want to be able to run it from the "ParentFolder" and have it apply the same command to every "Actor" folder I have.

Comment: will the files you want moved always be in a `HighRes` directory?

Comment: Yes it will always be in a directory called that. It would be nice to make a robust command that can take all files from that deep of a level, but for this instance yes.

Comment: Is there some kind of quick modification of the code I have already that could just make it look one folder deeper?

Comment: it's been so long since i did BAT/CMD stuff that i have no freaking idea what the details are of the code you posted. [*blush*] so i can't tell you anything about that.

Comment: Yea I just found the code online from someone else it worked in the individual instance I was talking about. If you know some other method of doing this it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: take a look at the answer i just posted. it is powershell - and as usual, it's rather wordy. AKA = "semi-self-documenting" ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

this gets a list of files in the `$TopDir` tree that match `*.mp4` AND have `HighRes` in the path name. it then iterates thru the list, gets the parent dir name, and moves the file to that parent dir.

remove the `-WhatIf` when you are ready to do it for real ... [*grin*]

```
$TopDir = "$env:TEMP\ParentFolder"
$Filter = '*.mp4'
$SourceDir = 'HighRes'

$MoveFileList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $TopDir -Filter $Filter -Recurse -File |
    Where-Object {$_.DirectoryName -match $SourceDir}

foreach ($MFL_Item in $MoveFileList)
    {
    $DestDir = Split-Path -Path $MFL_Item.DirectoryName -Parent
    Move-Item -LiteralPath $MFL_Item.FullName -Destination $DestDir -WhatIf
    }
```

output [reformatted to be easier to read] ...

```
What if: Performing the operation
    "Move File"
    on target
    "Item: C:\Temp\ParentFolder\Actor1\Movie\HighRes\HighresMovie.mp4
     Destination: C:\Temp\ParentFolder\Actor1\Movie\HighresMovie.mp4".
What if: Performing the operation
    "Move File"
    on target
    "Item: C:\Temp\ParentFolder\Actor2\Movie\HighRes\HighresMovie.mp4
     Destination: C:\Temp\ParentFolder\Actor2\Movie\HighresMovie.mp4".
```

Comment: That worked great! Is there a way to cleanup the empty folder afterwards somehow?

Comment: @TylerBoodman - yep! add `Remove-Item -LiteralPath $DestDir -WhatIf` after the `Move-Item` line & just before the last `}`.

Comment: @TylerBoodman - you are quite welcome! glad to have helped ... [*grin*]